# Linking error with HWLOC

Tags: c++, linker, makefile, runtime-error

I am trying to link hwloc (http://www.open-mpi.org/projects/hwloc/) to my very basic application.  Below are the details

main.cxx:

```
 #include <hwloc.h>
 #include <stdio.h>

 int main(int argc, char** argv) {
     hwloc_topology_t topology;
     int ncores;

     hwloc_topology_init(&topology);
     hwloc_topology_load(topology);

     ncores = hwloc_get_nbobjs_by_type(topology, HWLOC_OBJ_CORE);
     printf("Number of cores: %d\n", ncores);

     hwloc_topology_destroy(topology);

     return 0;
 }
```

Makefile:

```
 .SUFFIXES: .cxx .o

 CXX  = g++

 TARGET  = tests
 SRCS    = main.cxx

 OBJS   = $(SRCS:.cxx=.o)

 HWLOC_ROOT = $(CURDIR)/hwloc
 HWLOC_INCS = -I$(HWLOC_ROOT)/include
 HWLOC_LIBS = -L$(HWLOC_ROOT)/lib -lhwloc

 FLAGS   = -std=c++0x $(HWLOC_INCS)
 LDFLAGS = $(HWLOC_LIBS)

 %.o : %.cxx
    $(CXX) -c $(FLAGS) $<

 $(TARGET) : $(OBJS)
    $(CXX) -o $@ $^ $(LDFLAGS) -lstdc++

 clean :
    rm -rf *.o $(TARGET)
```

In the same directory as my two files (main.cxx and Makefile) is the directory containing hwloc.  It is correctly installed because I have used it before.

I can compile everything just fine.  When I run `./tests`, I get the following error:

```
 ./tests: error while loading shared libraries: libhwloc.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Inside ./hwloc:

```
 bin/  include/  lib/  share/
```

Inside ./hwloc/lib:

```
 libhwloc.la  libhwloc.so  libhwloc.so.5  libhwloc.so.5.3.1  pkgconfig/
```

It is clear the `libhwloc.so.5` exists so I'm not sure what the problem is.  I appreciate any help toward my issue.

**Edit:**

To clarify, the point is to not have to add the directory to my path.  I don't want to have to perform any command line commands in order for the linker to know where to locate libhwloc.so.5.  The goal is to be able to move the root directory of my application to anywhere on my computer or another computer and it still know where to locate libhwloc.so.5, since its packaged with the application.

Comment: Either add `./hwloc/lib` to the path variable in your user environment or move `libhwloc.so.5` to a directory already in the path (or add a link to it).

Comment: @CaptainObvlious I know that is an easy solution, but at the same time I should be able to get it to work without adding it to my path.  In the past I've used hwloc in my application directory (for reasons of portability) and had no problems with linking.  Of course I don't remember/don't have access to what I did before or else I wouldn't be here ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the purpose for LD_LIBRARY_PATH. If you have shared libraries in non-standard locations (i.e. not /usr/lib, /usr/local/lib, etc.), the dynamic loader needs to know where to find them. There are two primary ways to deal with that. For one-off libraries that are used infrequently, or for a small number of programs, setting the users LD_LIBRARY_PATH to contain the directory the library is in is sufficient. For more widespread use, you can make that directory one of the "standard" ones by adding it to the list of directories your loader knows about - on Linux that's typically done by editing files in `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` or `/etc/ld.so.conf` itself, and then running `ldconfig`. That will add that directory to the search path system-wide for all users and programs, so beware of potential conflicts.

Comment: Then what is the point of linking at compile time with the -L command? I guess my question is why doing -L$(HWLOC_LIBS) -lhwloc doesn't tell the loader where to find the library.

Comment: `-L` tells the linker where to find the library. LD_LIBRARY_PATH or the `ld.so` configuration tell the loader where to find the library. Another alternative is the compiler/linker flags that embed the full path of the library in the executable, but I don't remember what those are off the top of my head.

Answer (score 1):

You can enforce the runtime path of the lib at compile time with -Wl,-rpath,$(HWLOC_ROOT)/lib (which means gcc will pass "-rpath $(HWLOC_ROOT)/lib" to the linker) but that's not always a good idea.